# Getting byte array from a stream HIGH CPU usage on linux via MONO

Tags: c#, linux, mono

we are using this code on windows..
on widnows it getting 0% CPU usage
we are rebuilded code run into linux debian 10 and we are running it via MONO
Its getting 50%+ CPU usage:(

please help, how can we solve this to get 0% cpu usage..? without thread sleep...

Many thanks for your helping !!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace cpuissues
{
    public class Rec
    {
        
        public Rec()
        {
            start();
        }
        private void start()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread httP_start = new Thread(httpStart);
                httP_start.Start();
                //httpStart();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }


        private async void httpStart()
        {
            string url = "http://tviptv.iptv-channel.ru:8000/live/NndqUU6Xoe/mV6O7VmqLx/138.ts"; //"http://tviptv.iptv-channel.ru:8000/live/NndqUU6Xoe/mV6O7VmqLx/1.ts";

            try
            {

                // Console.WriteLine("About to open Webclient");
                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url))
                {
                    int bytesReceived = 1316; //must be used 1316 value for our purposes
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesReceived];
                    int i = 0;

                    while ((bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        i = i + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i));
                        //Thread.Sleep(100); //DO NOT USE THIS ... ITS NOT SOLUTION we need nonstop getting data...!
                    }

                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Mono rather than .NET Core?

Comment: What does the console output gives? small/large reads? compare them? Add the `byteReceived` to the console writeline

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually await the read otherwise you're just constantly looping:

Change this line:

```
while ((bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
```

to this:

```cs
while ((bytesReceived = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
```

You should also await the `OpenRead`:

```cs
using (Stream stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(url))
```

Comment: `You need to actually await the read otherwise you're just constantly looping` Why? I don't think that is true.

Comment: You may be right, looks like it may be some difference between Mono and Windows. But can't harm in an already async function...